Why alphafold3 have the error of jax: Failed to upgrade versioned StableHLO

jaxlib.xla_extension.XlaRuntimeError: INVALID_ARGUMENT: Failed to upgrade versioned StableHLO.

I have the correct version of AlphaFold 3 installed, but I keep encountering an error when loading the model parameters.
I try to change the version of Jax and Jaxlib, but it still can't solve the problem.
